# Changing glFrustum doesn't change viewport

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, objective-c++

I have a cube on the screen, I want to give the effect of zooming out so I was tweaking the frustum to be larger and larger.  Here is the code:

```
- (void)Draw {

    EAGLView* videoController = [EAGLView Instance];
    [videoController BeginDraw];

    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.7f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, videoController.mBackingWidth, videoController.mBackingHeight);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float mAspectRatio = 1.6666;
    static float mHalfViewAngleTan = 0.1;
    mHalfViewAngleTan += 1.1;
    float mNearZClip = 1.0;
    float mFarZClip = 1000.0;
    glFrustumf( mAspectRatio*-mHalfViewAngleTan, mAspectRatio*mHalfViewAngleTan, -mHalfViewAngleTan, mHalfViewAngleTan, mNearZClip, mFarZClip );

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    static float rotZ = 0.0f;
    ++rotZ;
    if(rotZ > 360)
        rotZ = 0;

    glRotatef(rotZ, 0, 0.5, 0.5);

    RenderModel(modelObj);

    [videoController EndDraw];
}
```

The glRotate is working correctly.  However as mHalfViewAngleTan gets larger nothing seems to be happening, the scene changes in no noticeable way.  I have tried smaller and larger numbers for the amount mHalfViewAngleTan increase per frame.  Changing the Near and Far plane are also working correctly.

There are no glMatrixMode/glPushMatrix calls inside RenderModel.  It Enables and Disables client state, sets up glVertPointer's and call glDrawArray.

All this code is in an .mm file calling into .cpp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem in the past.  I solved it by directly including the Open GL 1.1 or 2.2 headers.  Not quite sure why that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Set `mNearZClip` to something greater than zero.  See the [Notes](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glFrustum.xml).

Comment: It must account for that internally, changing the Near up to 1 doesn't do anything but clip one of my boxes.